# Why can't I backup more than 15 minutes of a DVD to iso using a raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, memory, backup, data-recovery, ddrescue

I am using a raspberry pi 3. I am attempting to backup a DVD as an *.iso file (3 year old's movie). I have downloaded/installed the vlc's libdvdcss. I have tried a 1 and 2 USB portable DVD drive. I have attempted to use the dvdbackup command and the ddrescue command and a couple others with no success. The recovery stops prematurely. I can successfully save 15 minutes of the DVD as an *.iso file and then the video stops.

I don't believe this is a lack of power issue. (2 USB plug DVD drive)

There is space on the storage card for the kid movie.

**Does anyone know why this is happening? or how to fix this?**

Please don't down vote before fully reading setup, hardware, and attempt details.

Comment: The raspberry pi3 has a 64 bit CPU but a 32 bit OS. When swap and memory  are greater then 2 GB it has a memory error. Check your log files.

Comment: Vlc's libdvdcss was the problem, the package was for debian, and although Raspbian is somehow related to debian, it is not close enough to function... An installation "appeared" to occur, but the package must be built on the system.